# Scrolling on single container, with body have overflow hidden

Tags: css

How can I get a single container to enable vertical scrolling? The body has `overflow hidden` and im using flexbox. Setting `overflow-y scroll` makes the scroll bar appear but its like greyed out and you still cant scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: try `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: Maybe the content isn't bigger that the container and thats why the scrollbar is inactive.

Comment: share your issue in fiddle, so that we can easily understand and resolve it.

Comment: add a Fiddle, to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using `height 100vh` instead of setting to 100%, then of course keeping `overflow-y scroll`